How can I set up iPhone Mirroring across distinct Apple IDs?
I use Apple hardware for me personally, and for work. I used to use my single personal Apple ID for everything, but then managed device restrictions like disallowing Time Machine floated down to my personal hardware, disabling it. I could re-enable it, until the management sync happened again. Ever since then, I now run purely personal devices on my personal Apple ID, and I create a separate Apple ID for my work devices.
Also these Apple IDs are linked as a Family, for what it's worth.
iPhone Mirroring just came out in iOS 18 + Sequoia, and I would LOVE to take advantage of it on my work machine, with my personal iPhone. However, Handoff only works using the same Apple ID. Is there a way, via direct connection, some sort of under the hood setting, something, to allow me to call up my personal iPhone on my work computer?
My current employer does use an Apple MDM, though they only have licenses for macOS machines. I've been speaking to them to see if I can add an MDM profile for the work account/Apple ID on my personal phone. Would this be enough? Would it limit me to data managed by the work profile? Or would it not work at all because it isn't the "system" (root most) Apple ID?
Is there a reverse method? A way to add my personal Apple ID on my work machine? I do not want to set up a second macOS user account on this machine and fast user switch, the point is to have the two Apple ID contents together as seamlessly as possible. … if possible.

I may have talked myself into Fast User Switching while writing this out. But I still posted it because I would love to know of additional possibilities.
